# How to remove Wagtail Core, Images, Documents from Django Admin

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a project that uses a Django app and a Wagtail App. In my Django admin (localhost/django-admin/) I get Wagtail panels that I want to hide. How could I do that?

Comment: please show your urls.py code

Comment: urls for the whole project or for the specific app?

Comment: whole project url

Comment: It is just the basic @c.grey . When i log into the django-admin I get panels that I want to remove (i.e. WAGTAIL CORE - Pages and Sites)

Comment: do you want to hide django core admin panel

Comment: In the django admin, I want to hide the Users group, and anything that is wagtail related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189000/discussion-between-c-grey-and-ajh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unregistering Wagtail models from the Django admin are basically the same as unregistering Django models. Had to check where the models are imported from.

Note: Make sure your own apps come after the django and wagtail core apps.

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/remove_default.html

```
from wagtail.images.models import Image
from wagtail.core.models import Site, Page
from wagtail.documents.models import Document

admin.site.unregister(Document)
admin.site.unregister(Site)
admin.site.unregister(Page)
admin.site.unregister(Image)
```